# Angular - update models using $resource after $update

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to figure out how to update my models with services, when I get a response from the server.

My JSON structure:

```
var dgs = [{id    :1,
            driver:'Sam',
            type:  'bus',
            segments:[ {id:1,origin:'the bakery',arrival:'the store'},
                     {id:2,origin:'the store' ,arrival:'somewhere'}]
            },
            { ... },
            { ... }
          ];
```

index.html:

```
<body ng-controller="dgCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="dg in dgs" drivegroup></div>
</body>
```

dg.html:

```
<div> {{ dg.driver }} </div>
<div> {{ dg.type }} </div>
<div ng-repeat="seg in dg.segments" segments></div>
```

segments.html:

```
<div>
  <input ng-model="seg.origin" ng-blur="updateSegment()"/></div>
<div>
  <input ng-model="seg.arrival" ng-blur="updateSegment()"/></div>
```

My controller is the following:

```
function dgCtrl($scope,$http,DriveGroup,Segment) {
  var segment =  new Segment;
  $scope.dgs = DriveGroup.query();  // load & display all drive groups

  $scope.updateSegment = function() {
    var seg = this.seg;
    segment.seg = this.seg;
    segment.id = this.seg.id;
    segment.$update(function(data,x) {
      // seg.origin = data.origin - This updates the origin.
      seg = data; // This doesn't work. How can I do this?
  });
}
```

My services:

```
angular.module('dgService',['ngResource']).
  factory("DriveGroup",function($resource) {
    return $resource(
      '/path/dgs',
      {},
      {update:{method:'PUT'}}
    );
});

angular.module('Segment',['ngResource']).
  factory('Segment',function($resource) {
    return $resource(
      '/path/seg/:id',
      {id:'@id'},
      {update:{method:'PUT'}}
    );
});
```

My problem is I'm not sure how to update on a per-segment basis using `$resource`. I want to make a change on a certain segment, so I make a `put` request. I get the response from the server and want to update my model (which isn't working).

I'm new to Angular, so if you see any other blatant mistakes/or structure issues suggestions are appreciated. Thanks.

**EDIT**:

The following achieves the results I want, but is this correct?

```
$scope.updateSegment = function() {
  var seg = this.seg,
      segment = new Segment(seg);

  segment.$update(function(data,x) {
    angular.extend(seg,data);
  });
}
```

Comment: using "angular.extend(...)", not sure if this is a good way or what potential side-effects are. Thanks anyway.